# "Solutions" for creating a DB, tables, columns and populating tables?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to make code that does this kind of task:

```
check if a given database exists.
1a-->if no, then create a DB, make some tables in it and some columns too.

   1.1-->Check if certain columns in a "list" exist. 
         Create those columns which don't exist yet.
   1.2--> once 1.1 is done, populate these tables with some test data. 

1b-->else check if certain tables exist and create them if they 
     don't exist. After that, do the stuff mentioned in 1.1 and 1.2
```

Do I make my own code or is there a "solution" which already exists for this kind of task ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest something else [flyway](http://code.google.com/p/flyway/wiki/GettingStarted), hopefully you'll feel it easier to grasp

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of anything built-in with what you are asking, but I believe you can achieve what you need with [LiquiBase](http://www.liquibase.org/).

Comment: Thanks ! that looks like what i need. But it will be a huge learning curve for me. Is there some small-sized api or code that can do the task ? I can code it myself, but it will be a pain.